# Why do I receive a memory error in python for this program?

Tags: python, function, math, arithmetic-expressions

I am a beginner in python and working on a starter programming project where I want to:

Estimate the number of calories in one cubic mile of chocolate ice cream.
Note: There are 5,280 feet in a mile and one cubic foot of chocolate ice cream contains about 48,600 calories.

My code:

```
Onemile = 5280
cubicmile = 5280**3
calories = 48,600
print("Number of calories per cubic mile:",cubicmile*calories)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-100-90c2410fa01f>", line 4, in <module>
    print("Number of calories per cubic mile:",cubicmile*calories)

MemoryError
```

Why does this happen? Is there an issue with the way I am framing the equation?

Comment: Note that using a comma is the problem; wouldn't have expected a memory error but you want to either calories = 48600

Comment: `calories` is a tuple of `(48, 600)`, when you multiply a tuple you get the tuple repeated, i.e. `(48, 600, 48, 600, ...)` `5280**3` times - which runs out of memory.

Comment: You can use `_` instead of the comma to separate thousands (for readability). `calories = 48_600`

Answer (score 4):

As noted, the problem is the line `calories = 48,600`.

The problem is that due to the `,` on the right side, this is the same as `calories = (48, 600)`, which is a `tuple`. And for tuples, multiplication means "repeat the tuple `n` times". So e.g. `2 * (48, 600) == (48, 600, 48, 600)`.

But since you do `5280**3 * calories`, this is trying to allocate a tuple with `2 * 5280**3 = 294395904000` elements, which seems to be too big to fit into your memory (assuming 64bits per value, this would be 2.14 TiB, which is larger than most peoples memory).

Note that in [Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-515-underscores-in-numeric-literals) you can use `_` as a separator for thousands:

```
calories = 48_600
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to print the tuple `(48, 600)` (that's what you get when you write `calories = 48,600`) `147197952000` times.

Your output *would* be:

```
Number of calories per cubic mile: (48, 600, 48, 600, 48, 600, ... , 48, 600)
```

Your pc simply cannot handle the approx. `1324781568000` characters that you want to dump at once.

Instead of using `,` as a thousand separator, you should just write `48600`.

```
Onemile = 5280
cubicmile = 5280**3
calories = 48600
print("Number of calories per cubic mile:",cubicmile*calories)
```

Output:

```
Number of calories per cubic mile: 7153820467200000
```

**Edit:**

Actually, it's not the printing or the creating of such a large string that fails, because it seems - at least for me - that Python will run out of memory when attempting to create `147197952000` pointers to the tuple, which you can test by running only `(48,600) * 147197952000`.